# Getting fan speed programmatically in Windows?

Tags: windows, openhardwaremonitor

This questions has been asked many times, but with no satisfying answer so far. Or I haven't found it.

**How do I read the speed of my CPU fan under Windows?** I don't really care, if it is by code or by parsing the stdout of another tool. I just want to read the value, not setting or change it.

I've tried WMI class Win32_Fan, but it didn't give me any results.
Then there's the C# based [Open Hardware Monitor](https://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/source/browse/trunk/), which shows the fan speed. But I don't have any experience of C# and so far I could not find out how that code works in regard to fan speeds. I am experienced in Python, Java and C++.

[image: Fan #1 is the object of interest]

Comment: So you *found* a solution, but need to learn C#?

Comment: Can't be the only way, can it?

Comment: see [my answer here using python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262603/accessing-cpu-temperature-in-python/32840852#answer-32840852