# PythonNet FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly

Tags: python, .net, python-2.7, ironpython, python.net

I am trying to execute a Python script that uses Python For .Net (https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) to load a C# library called "Kratos_3.dll" which is in the same folder as the script but the file cannot be found.

I have installed clr using "pip install pythonnet".

This is my script:

```
import clr
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"C:\\dev\\proj_1\\")
clr.AddReference("Kratos_3")
```

I keep getting the error

```
FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'Kratos_3. at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
```

When I run this using IronPython it works, but I would like to get this to work using regular Python 2.7, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turns out that even though I added the path through

```
sys.path.insert(0,"C:\\dev\\proj_1\\")
```

it still couldn't find the file because the .dll because Windows was not enabling it to load from "external sources". To fix this:

1. Right-click on the .dll
2. "Properties"
3. Under "General", click "Unblock"

Comment: I spent so much time fixing it. Nowhere I could have thought of 'Unblock'. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thank you so much, could have spend hours on this!

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 9):

Another possible reason Python for NET is unable to find lib is different platforms of Python and assemblies.
Python 64-bit can't see x86 Dlls, and Python 32-bit can't see x64. Make sure your lib match Python platform, or compile them as AnyCPU.