# Get sensor values (like Temperature of GPU and CPU) and fan speeds of Windows 10 PC

Tags: python, windows, wmi, cpu, temperature

I've been trying to get a Python script to show temperatures for CPU, GPU and other availabile sensors in my hardware, but I haven't found anything useful.

I tried using WMI to get those values, but my processor is apparently not supported.

The code I used was:

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\wmi")
temperature_info = w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0]
print temperature_info.CurrentTemperature
```

which I got from another stackoverflow thread, and I get thrown the error
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    temperature_info = w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 819, in query
    handle_com_error ()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217396, 'OLE error 0x8004100c', None, None)>
```

which, according to Microsoft Support, means `Not Supported (0x8004100C)`

I have tried running the command-line version of this code in a cmd.exe window ran as an administrator, but I got the same error.

Is there any other way to access CPU and GPU temperatures?

PS: My OS is Windows 10 and my CPU is AMD FX-8350. I am unsure whether my OS or my CPU are at fault for this error.

Comment: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262603/accessing-cpu-temperature-in-python) asks the same and already some answers to use OpenHardwareMonitor via its WMI interface.

Comment: @Sadap thanks. It's been 3 years though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get your GPU temperature.

Use nvidia-smi tool.

This is .exe file present in the location "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI".

In the command prompt, just enter:

```
cd C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI
```

then type:

```
nvidia-smi
```

This will display an output like this:

[image]

You can see the GPU temp! (red underline)

Coming to the CPU and Fan speed values, Microsoft apparently does not have a built in functionality to at least showcase these values to the user. But you can try 3rd part applications like [MSI Afterburner](https://www.maketecheasier.com/check-cpu-temperature-windows10/). But [Microsoft strictly warns against this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/how-to-check-cpu-temperature-in-windows-10/e287340a-1ca3-4a5a-b98d-e3972f3e2736) as this might affect the performance.