# Accessing GPU temperature in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, gpu, hardware, monitor

I'm currently trying to set up a kind of "monitor" for a cryptocurrency mining rig and want to watch the temperature of my rig.

As I can't find any way to access the GPU temperature with Python I wanted to ask if there's any known  way to get these values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262603/accessing-cpu-temperature-in-python this is a good place to start, might help out

Answer (score 0):

[Glances](https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/)

Or [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil):

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.sensors_temperatures()
{'pch_skylake': [shwtemp(label='', current=43.0, high=None, critical=None)], 'coretemp': [shwtemp(label='Package id 0', current=29.0, high=84.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=26.0, high=84.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 1', current=26.0, high=84.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 2', current=25.0, high=84.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 3', current=24.0, high=84.0, critical=100.0)], 'acpitz': [shwtemp(label='', current=27.8, high=119.0, critical=119.0), shwtemp(label='', current=29.8, high=119.0, critical=119.0)]}
```

Comment: The sensors_temperatures-method is currently only available on linux!