# How can I get CPU temperature in Python? Assuming that I have Windows 32-bits

Tags: python, windows, winapi, cpu, temperature

I have tried with `psutil` library using `sensors_temperatures()`, but it is giving me an AttributeError. Here is my code:

```
import psutil
print(psutil.sensors_temperatures())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-fbefe6006680> in <module>
----> 1 print(psutil.sensors_temperatures())

AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'sensors_temperatures'
```

Moreover, it seems that the function `sensors_temperatures()` do no longer exist in `psutil` when I checked it with `help(psutil)`

Comment: `sensors_temperatures` is only available on Linux: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1271

Comment: Related: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/hskdteyh(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262603/accessing-cpu-temperature-in-python Windows system is FUNNY :). Drivers are required - for each type of chipset separately. In Linux, however, just read the port. Linux is more versatile, although there are many distributions than Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing CPU temperature in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262603/accessing-cpu-temperature-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir you can use simple code for find the CPU temperature using python. And it is not necessary that you should use only 'psutil' for finding the temperature.
You can usethe WMI module + Open Hardware Monitor + its WMI interface described here.

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\OpenHardwareMonitor")
temperature_infos = w.Sensor()
for sensor in temperature_infos:
    if sensor.SensorType==u'Temperature':
        print(sensor.Name)
        print(sensor.Value)

# This is a simple code to find the temperature of the CPU using Python.
```

Comment: Error: wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217394, 'OLE error 0x8004100e', None, None)>