# python cpu and gpu program issue

Tags: python

im trying to create a script in python that retrives the cpu and gpu of a pc, i tried couple of ways to do so but with no succeses unfortunately.

i tried using wmi but with no succeses there with a lot of errors and when the program did work i got a values of 0 and 300, which i dont think my pc is on haha.

i tried using psutil with sensors_temperatures() function but no matter what i did this function cannot be found by visual studio code (got a no module name sensors_temperatures() error) with versions 5.8.0 and 5.9.6/7

could you please help me build a program that gets the cpu and gpu tempuatre using python?

thanks to all the helpers

Comment: try this ? works for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617789/get-cpu-and-gpu-temp-using-python-windows