# Python clr not finding a dll

Tags: python, dll, wmi

I'm trying to include a DLL into my python project but I'm having a terrible time.

I was following this thread:
[Accessing CPU temperature in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262603/accessing-cpu-temperature-in-python)
But I can't get the thing to import the file.
I'm getting:
Unable to import 'OpenHardwareMonitor'pylint(import-error)

I also placed the DLL into System32 folder and tried including it without the path with no luck.
Any ideas?

Folder:
OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll
Test.py

```
import clr #package pythonnet, not clr
import os
openhardwaremonitor_hwtypes = ['Mainboard','SuperIO','CPU','RAM','GpuNvidia','GpuAti','TBalancer','Heatmaster','HDD']


dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

print ("Path:")
print (dir_path)
print ()

file = dir_path + "OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll"

clr.AddReference(file)
from OpenHardwareMonitor import Hardware
```

Comment: same here: when the file is not present, got a short error: can't load, but when present, the error is the same but a longer one from System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad. Is a dependency needed?

Comment: The problem seems to be my python is 64bits but the dll is 32bits.